react native expo metro-blunder
It happens that when I do npx expo start I get these warnings and errors, this did not happen to me yesterday, it started happening from today without having touched any code.
So far I haven't found any solution, I've already removed node_modules and the package-look.json to reinstall all the dependencies, as well as metro and babel, but I can't find any results. If someone has already had the same thing happen to them and has a solution, it would be very helpful. I've also been looking at the compatibility of dependencies, and all my dependencies are now compatible, there is no conflict between them, so I can't find where it's failing.
npx expo start
Starting project at /home/gabriel/stock-rn
● Validation Warning:

Unknown option "serializer.postProcessBundleSourcemap" with value ({ code, map, outFileName }) => ({
  code,
  map,
}) was found.
This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

● Validation Warning:

Unknown option "server.experimentalImportBundleSupport" with value false was found.
This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

● Validation Warning:

Unknown option "server.runInspectorProxy" with value true was found.
This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

Starting Metro Bundler 
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █   █▄▄▀▄▀█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █
█ █   █ █ ▀▄ █▀▄▀▄█ █   █ █
█ █▄▄▄█ █▀██▀▀█▀▄██ █▄▄▄█ █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▀▄█ █▄█▄█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
█▄ ▀█▄ ▄▀█▀▀▄▀█▄ ███ ▀▄▄ ▄█
█▄█  ██▄▀██▀ ▄██ ▀▀ █▄  ▀██
█ ▀ ▀▄█▄▄██▄█▄▀▄▀▄▀▄▀▀▄ ▀██
███ ▀▀▄▄ ▄ ▀█▀██▄▄▄█▄▀ ▀███
█▄▄█▄█▄▄▄▀  ▄▀█▄▄ ▄▄▄ ▀ ▄▄█
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▀█▀ ▄██▀ █▄█ ▀▀█▀█
█ █   █ █▄▄▀█▄▀▄█▄▄ ▄▄▀   █
█ █▄▄▄█ █▀▀██▀█▀▄██▄▀█▀▀ ██  
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄█▄▄▄▄████▄▄▄▄▄▄█

› Metro waiting on exp://192.168.1.33:8081
› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

› Using Expo Go
› Press s │ switch to development build

› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press j │ open debugger
› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu
› Press o │ open project code in your editor

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Android Bundling failed 5988ms node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js (368 modules)
error: App.js: /home/gabriel/stock-rn/App.js: Duplicate __self prop found. You are most likely using the deprecated transform-react-jsx-self Babel plugin. Both __source and __self are automatically set when using the automatic runtime. Please remove transform-react-jsx-source and transform-react-jsx-self from your Babel config.
16 |        <SafeAreaProvider>
17 |            <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
> 18 |                <IndexNavigation />
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  19 |          </SafeAreaView>
  20 |     </SafeAreaProvider>
  21 |   </Provider>


Try to reset cache by using this command: npx react-native start --reset-cache

I solved it by adding a mtro.config.js file since it was not included in the metro modules, also by installing @react-native/js-polyfills metro-config @react-native/metro-babel-transformer metro-runtime @react-native/metro-config.
But now I have the problem that when I create the apk with eas and install it on my mobile device, it closes instantly
